# Merge Image with GIF - FFMPEG

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I would like to take an image and add it to the start of a gif file.

image should be displayed for 2 seconds then the gif will play.

no looping is needed.

Edit 1:

I've also been looking at this: https://github.com/jtlapp/gifwrap

Edit 2:

I want to merge the files together, creating a new gif, which has the image and original gif.

Answer (score -1):

Make a countdown timer, where you have a integer seconds which you keep track on. Whenever seconds gets above 2 seconds, then display the gif.

Comment: I need this to be 1 solid gif, which can be viewed anywhere i share the image.

Comment: see edits......